# SQL Server, group by , aggregate into single result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL query that returns the data into multiple records (the first 4 records).

[image]

How can I combine the 4 rows above into one single record result?

The product where Type is null has only V1, V1_Status, V2 and V2_Status

In my query I already do:

```
SELECT Product, Max(Type), Max(V1), Max(V1_Status), Max(V2), Max(V2_Status), Max(V3), Max(V3_Status), Max(V4), Max(V4_Status), Max(V5), Max(V5_Status)
FROM Table 
WHERE condition
GROUP BY Product, Type
```

Comment: Remove `Type` from the `Group By` for starters. See what that gives you.

Comment: Performing `MAX` on a column you're grouping by is pointless; it'll have no affect as the `MAX` and `MIN` within the group are the same value.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to not `GROUP BY Type` i.e.

```
SELECT Product, 
Max(V1), 
Max(V1_Status), 
Max(V2), 
Max(V2_Status), 
Max(V3), 
Max(V3_Status), 
Max(V4), 
Max(V4_Status), 
Max(V5), 
Max(V5_Status)
FROM Table 
WHERE condition
GROUP BY Product
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from    
(
select t.*,row_number()over(partition by product order by v1 desc) rn
from table_name t
) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: I don't think that will work here. This needs some aggregation.